# windows use llmnr only for local domain

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

I config my local dns server to resolve a local domain (for example wpad) to 10.0.0.2.

I can ping wpad and get 10.0.0.2 under linux.

But under win 7,  I ping wpad and get "ping request cannot find host", while nslookup wpad and get the right answer.

By using Wireshark, I found it only send LLMNR request to resolve wpad when ping.

It should be sending LLMNR request after the dns request is failed.

So what's the problem?

Comment: You're probably not using a DNS suffix on the Windows 7 client that matches your DNS zone. If you want Windows 7 to send queries for the zone then it needs to use a DNS suffix that matches the zone. Without that, how would it ever know to query for wpad.domain.local or anything in the domain.local zone?

Comment: I try using a DNS suffix both client and server and success. Is there any way not using any DNS suffix?

Comment: You could probably use WINS (not recommended) or you could deploy a GlobalNames zone - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731744.aspx